# mySQL remote database not connecting

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform

Is there something I am missing?
My remote MySQL database is on Google Cloud and I gave access to my current external IP:

```
String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://<remote IP address here>:3306/test";
System.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
System.setProperty("user", "test");
System.setProperty("password", "test");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","lib\\keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password here");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","lib\\truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password here");
Class.forName(myDriver);
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, System.getProperties());
System.out.println("Connection successful.");
```

It's telling me access denied.

here is the stacktrace:

```
Access denied for user 'test'@'my external IP' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'test'@'my external IP' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Comment: Show details/stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can telnet the ip address using the following command.
telnet remote-ip port.

As an example if u telnet google @ port 80:

telnet 8.8.8.8 80

You will see this response:

Trying 8.8.8.8...
Connected to 8.8.8.8.
Escape character is '^]'.

The similar result should be observed when u telnet remote-ip. If not either that port is not open at google cloud or your ISP provider is blocking the outgoing traffic @ port 3306.

Comment: i have mySQL Workbench and i can connect to my remote database from it and i access it via SSL and such, why would i need to try to telnet ? plus my laptop that i am currently working on has windows 10